# Time series analysis of tick data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some statistical analysis of market data and have managed to get the tick data from my trading platform into a python data frame in the format shown below.

I need to run a test to see how often does the day session (09:30-16:15) equal or exceed the high or low printed in the rest of the session (16:15 - 09:30).  Can anyone help me with this please?

```
print (df.iloc[85:95])
                              Price  bidVol  askVol
2015-12-28 08:39:12.000000  2041.00       2       0
2015-12-28 08:39:12.001000  2041.00       1       0
2015-12-28 08:47:19.000000  2041.25       0       2
2015-12-28 09:18:00.999999  2040.25       0       5
2015-12-28 09:33:30.000000  2039.75       0       1
2015-12-28 09:35:58.000000  2039.75       0       5
2015-12-28 09:44:35.000000  2039.75       1       0
2015-12-28 09:58:39.999999  2039.00       0       1
2015-12-28 09:58:55.000000  2039.25       1       0
2015-12-28 10:02:59.000000  2038.50       1       0
```

Desired output:

```
high 2015-12-28  True or False
low  2015-12-28  True or False
```

I try:

```
#Define day and night session and apply to tick data 
daystart = datetime.time(9,30,0) 
dayend = datetime.time(16,14,59) 
day_session = pd.between_time(start,end) 
night_session = pd.between_time(end,start) 
#Resample using daily timeframe 
day_session.resample('D', how='ohlc') 
night_session.resample('D', how='ohlc')
```

[All data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/tubus.h5).

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think the best is sample of data, desired output and code what do you try, maybe pseudocode.

Comment: Not sure how to code it but I will try to explain better.

First I need to split the day (09:30-16:14:59) and night session  (16:15 - 09:29:59) for each day and get the high and low.

Then I need to check if the high of day session is >= high of night session.
Then check if the low of day session is <= low of night session.  The data is over a gig so I just gave the example output above of the data frame.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, can you add sample with 10 rows of data with different days and desired output? Because in question is only 5 rows  but day is same and it cannot be separated, because no data with `09:30-16:14:59`.

Comment: Hi Jezreal, I added additional data from 2016-01-06 covering night and day session.  Desired output is one row for each day showing a true or false if the high of day session is >= high of night session or the low of day session is <= low of night session.

Comment: Would it help to upload the data to dropbox or is anyone able to help with the information provided, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. But I cannot help you now but later.

Comment: Now I have time for you. Can you share data?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/tubus.h5

Comment: Hi Jezrael, did you manage to download the data? Cheers

Comment: First it doesnt work, but I try again.

Comment: Do you need another format?

Comment: No, but now i have slowly internet connection.

Comment: Is the file too big Jezrael? Thanks

Comment: adele, you have to be very angry for me. But yesterday I flew from conference, so I try solve your problem. Sorry.

Comment: I have tried to progress this further as follows:

`#Define day and night session and apply to tick data

daystart = datetime.time(9,30,0)
dayend = datetime.time(16,14,59)

day_session = pd.between_time(start,end)
night_session = pd.between_time(end,start)

#Resample using daily timeframe 

day_session.resample('D', how='ohlc')
night_session.resample('D', how='ohlc')`

How do I now compare this data showing a true or false if the high of day session is >= high of night session or the low of day session is <= low of night session.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate any help so whenever is convenient for you is great Jezrael.  Please ignore my previous entry if there is a better way to approach this.

Comment: It looks good, I try use it.

Comment: adele,I think your pandas version is `0.15.1`. Can you upgrade to last `0.18.1`?

Comment: Ok, I solve your problem. Do you need compare columns high and low in `day_session.resample('D', how='ohlc')` and `night_session.resample('D', how='ohlc')`? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: And columns high and low are counted from column Price only?

Comment: Yes thanks, I may use the other columns later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

#for all data remove iloc[85:95]
df = pd.read_hdf('tubus.h5').iloc[85:95]
print (df)
                              Price  bidVol  askVol
2015-12-28 08:39:12.000000  2041.00       2       0
2015-12-28 08:39:12.001000  2041.00       1       0
2015-12-28 08:47:19.000000  2041.25       0       2
2015-12-28 09:18:00.999999  2040.25       0       5
2015-12-28 09:33:30.000000  2039.75       0       1
2015-12-28 09:35:58.000000  2039.75       0       5
2015-12-28 09:44:35.000000  2039.75       1       0
2015-12-28 09:58:39.999999  2039.00       0       1
2015-12-28 09:58:55.000000  2039.25       1       0
2015-12-28 10:02:59.000000  2038.50       1       0
```

```
daystart = '9:30'
dayend = '16:14:59'

#filter day data, include start and end 
day_session = df.between_time(daystart,dayend, include_start=True, include_end=True)
print (day_session.head())
                              Price  bidVol  askVol
2015-12-28 09:33:30.000000  2039.75       0       1
2015-12-28 09:35:58.000000  2039.75       0       5
2015-12-28 09:44:35.000000  2039.75       1       0
2015-12-28 09:58:39.999999  2039.00       0       1
2015-12-28 09:58:55.000000  2039.25       1       0

#filter night data, exclude start and end
night_session = df.between_time(dayend,daystart, include_start=False, include_end=False)
print (night_session.head())
                              Price  bidVol  askVol
2015-12-28 08:39:12.000000  2041.00       2       0
2015-12-28 08:39:12.001000  2041.00       1       0
2015-12-28 08:47:19.000000  2041.25       0       2
2015-12-28 09:18:00.999999  2040.25       0       5
```

```
#resample only column Price
#version above 0.18.0
df_day = day_session.Price.resample('D').ohlc()
df_night = night_session.Price.resample('D').ohlc()

#version bellow 0.18.0
#df_day = day_session.Price.resample('D', how='ohlc')
#df_night = night_session.Price.resample('D', how='ohlc')


#day data are longer as nightly, so you need reindex them
df_day = df_day.reindex(df_night.index)

print (df_day)
               open     high     low   close
2015-12-28  2039.75  2039.75  2038.5  2038.5

print (df_night)
              open     high      low    close
2015-12-28  2041.0  2041.25  2040.25  2040.25

#compare columns high and low
print (df_day.high >=  df_night.high)
2015-12-28    False
Freq: D, Name: high, dtype: bool

print (df_day.low <= df_night.low)
2015-12-28    True
Freq: D, Name: low, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is really great Jezrael thanks so much.  Is it possible to have a data frame so there would be columns df_day, df_night, df_day.high >=  df_night.high and df_day.low <= df_night.low)?

Comment: Shall I ask this in new question Jezrael?

Comment: I am little bit confused, because `df_day` and `df_night` are DataFrames with 8 columns together. So output is `10` columns? Or you need `df_day.high`, `df_day.low` + same for night + `df_day.high >= df_night.high` and `df_day.low <= df_night.low`) - output with `6` columns?

Comment: Yes the output is 10 columns so I can see all the data.  I will also need to use the dropna option to remove any missing rows.  The reason I am looking at this is to get statistics on how often the low or high is passed.  Thanks

Comment: @adele, I think you can create new question. And dont forget add desired output. Thanks.